# How do I implement word count in Python?

Tags: python

```
x="I use computers"
print (x)
y=x[0:1]
y1=x[2:5]
y2=x[6:15]
n=(y+y1+y2)
print len(n)
```

I know this counts the number of letters but how do I count the number of words in the sentence?

Comment: `len(mystring.split())`

Comment: @voithos, faster: `mystring.count(' ') + 1`

Comment: @Junuxx Not really, they do different things. `mystring.count(' ') + 1` counts the number of spaces in a string and adds one. Consider a string with extra spaces between words. Your method will not return the correct number of words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this piece of code

```
x = "I use computers"
print len(x.split())
```

Comment: You don't necessarily need the explicit `' '`, since `.split()` divides on whitespace by default.

Comment: not only unnecessary, but incorrect. if you have words separated by multiple spaces, you're output list will not be what you want

Comment: @voithos ,@xhainingx you both are right .split() divides on whitespace by default.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just interested in **counting** the words, not in splitting the string into words, `split()` does unnecessary work. By counting the number of spaces and adding one, you get the number of words much faster. Though this does assume that all words are separated by a single space, not more.

Proof:

```
>>>import timeit 
>>> timeit.timeit("len(x.split())", setup='x="I use computers"' , number=10**6)

0.28843931717636195
>>> timeit.timeit("x.count(' ')+1", setup='x="I use computers"' , number=10**6)

0.19020372901493232
```

Comment: This will return the wrong answer if the string has multiple spaces in a row or uses other whitespace characters (e.g. `\t`). Also, what if the string is empty, or is just whitespace?

Comment: @voithos: Yes, I mentioned that assumption. It's just a slight optimization if we assume that it is used on actual text. Not supposed to work on all freak cases ;)

Comment: @voithos Its not difficult to find words separated by multiple spaces in "actual text". For example, [this](http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/244/pg244.txt) document has many, search for 'START: FULL LICENSE'. I count 72 occurrences of two spaces in a row between words from there to the end of the document. (ignoring extra spaces for indentation)

Comment: I fully agree with both of you - this requires single spaced words. But the efficiency of returning a full list of words when you're just interested in the spaces bothered me more.